# group unique records for a customerID by date and track total records of customerID

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the a set of mongo documents by month and year. The current query I have works:

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        {
            $project:
            {
                cust_ID : '$request.headers.custID',
                cost : '$request.body.expectedPrice',
                year :
                {
                    $year:  '$date'
                },
                month:
                {
                    $month: '$date'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match:
            {
                year : year,
                month: month
            }
        }
    );
```

But I also need to aggregate/push total orders by customer ID, so I added this to the middle stage of the query between `$project` and `$match`. The query is coming back **empty**, even thought I know there are results:

```
        {
            $group:
            {
                "_id": "$request.headers.custID",
                "custID" : {
                    "$first" : "$request.headers.custID"
                },
                "orders":
                {
                    "$push":
                    {
                        "order": "$request.body"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I would add this aggregator `push` to $project, but $project doesn't support that. How can I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have new fields via the **`$project`** pipeline, you should pass them on to the next pipeline step as they are defined:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$project": {
            cust_ID: '$request.headers.custID',
            "cost": '$request.body.expectedPrice',
            "year": { "$year":  '$date' },
            "month": { "$month": '$date' },
            "order": "request.body"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "year": year,
            "month": month
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$cust_ID",
            "custID": { "$first" : "$cust_ID" },
            "cost": { "$first" : "$cost" },
            "orders": { "$push": "$order" }                
        }
    },
]

var query = Order.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am losing the field `cost`. Is this because I didn't continue piping the cost field from `$project` into `$group`? I find the use of "", $, and "$", etc confusing. Why does `$project` need to be in quotes, and `$match` doesn't? Why is `order` in quotes, and the rest of those fields arent? (`cust_ID`, `cost`, etc)? In `$group`, why is it `"order" : "$order"`? I find this confusing

Comment: I've modified my answer to include the `cost` field in the `$group` pipeline via the `$first` operator. The use of the `$` character shouldn't be that intimidating as this is how mongo interprets the document fields in the pipelines, The quotes are really not necessary unless if you are wrapping an embedded field with the dot notation which should be enclosed in strings. Finally, the statement `"orders": { "$push": { "order": "$order" } }` will create a document array like e.g. `{ ..., "orders": [ { "order": "ABC" }, { "order": "XYZ" }], .. }`.